# localhost / userdir on macOS Sierra

Tags: webserver, macos

I've always used: [Setting up a local web server on OS X](https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-3083) to set up my localhost and userdirs.

After upgrading to Sierra, yesterday, my localhost web server wasn't working anymore.

I tried following the tutorial again but I'm not able to get into my userdir.

localhost works:

[image: works]

user shortname - fails:

[image: fail]

Are there any other configurations that need to be made on Sierra to get userdirs to work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is an updated tutorial here: [How to Set up Apache in macOS Sierra 10.12](https://web.archive.org/web/20161018141829/http://digitalshore.io/local-web-development-environment-apache-macos-sierra-10-12/)

It includes **extra** configurations like uncommenting the following lines by removing the "#":

> #LoadModule userdir_module libexec/apache2/mod_userdir.so
>   ...
>   #LoadModule vhost_alias_module libexec/apache2/mod_vhost_alias.so
>   ...
>   #Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-userdir.conf
>   ...
>   #Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

in `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`

and uncommenting:

> #Include /private/etc/apache2/users/*.conf

in `/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-userdir.conf`

and restarting apache: `sudo apachectl restart`

It should work.

Comment: You said "_It should work._", but does it!?

Comment: @user3439894 yeah it does, for me.

Comment: In Sierra, I get the following error: when files in the user directory aren't found, Sierra tries to find them in localhost. But localhost is not accessible, I get the error: 403 Forbidden. What setting could have changed in Sierra? It worked in El Capitan.

Comment: i'm getting a 403 forbidden, and your link is dead

Comment: The answer above is only the specific changes made in Sierra, you still need to make the basic other changes that you did before on other OS's. You can look at the link in the question.

Comment: @abbood the link is working again now, jsyk

Comment: Nice concise summary of the link! Worked for me.