# How to set up Document Root as "Sites" folder in Apache on macOS Sierra?

Tags: macos, apache, webserver

I have an `index.html` in my `/Users/igor/Sites/MySite` folder (`igor` is my username on Mac). Links (for example: `<a href="/page">Page</a>`) all go to `localhost/page` instead of `http://localhost/~igor/MySite/page`. `http://localhost` reports `It works!`, in `http://localhost/~igor/` I see all my files and folders.

My `/private/etc/apache2/users/igor.conf` file:

```
<Directory "/Users/igor/Sites/">
AllowOverride All
Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

My `/private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-userdir.conf` file (without comments):

```
UserDir Sites  
Include /private/etc/apache2/users/*.conf
<IfModule bonjour_module>
       RegisterUserSite customized-users
</IfModule>
```

Also I uncommented lines in `httpd.conf` as described [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/253884/localhost-userdir-on-macos-sierra).

Some lines from my `httpd.conf`:

```
User _www
Group _www


 <Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>  



<Directory "/Library/WebServer/Documents">
    Options FollowSymLinks Multiviews
    MultiviewsMatch Any

    AllowOverride None

    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

`httpd -V` output:

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.23 (Unix)
Server built:   Aug  8 2016 16:31:34
Server's Module Magic Number: 20120211:61
Server loaded:  APR 1.5.2, APR-UTIL 1.5.4
Compiled using: APR 1.5.2, APR-UTIL 1.5.4
Architecture:   64-bit
Server MPM:     prefork
  threaded:     no
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP
 -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
 -D APR_USE_FLOCK_SERIALIZE
 -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
 -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
 -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
 -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
 -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=256
 -D HTTPD_ROOT="/usr"
 -D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/bin/suexec"
 -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="/private/var/run/httpd.pid"
 -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
 -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
 -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="/private/etc/apache2/mime.types"
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf"
```

How to fix links so they correspond to `Sites/MySite/MyLink` and not `localhost/MyLink`? Thanks.

Update: `httpd -t -D DUMP_RUN_CFG` returns:

```
[Thu Oct 13 16:55:24.277291 2016] [so:warn] [pid 46810] AH01574: module php5_module is already loaded, skipping
AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/usr/docs/dummy-host.example.com] does not exist
AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/usr/docs/dummy-host2.example.com] does not exist
ServerRoot: "/usr"
Main DocumentRoot: "/Library/WebServer/Documents"
Main ErrorLog: "/private/var/log/apache2/error_log"
Mutex default: dir="/private/var/run/" mechanism=default 
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
PidFile: "/private/var/run/httpd.pid"
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="_www" id=70 not_used
Group: name="_www" id=70 not_used
```

Comment: Just a hint..."line numbers" are irrelevant in `httpd.conf` you need to reference the *directives* (like DocumentRoot).  Directives can be located anywhere in httpd.conf and httpd.conf files differ by distro, Apache version and by user so line numbers don't help.

Comment: I'm not seeing DocumentRoot, but I see that you have a directory in `/Library/WebServer/Documents/`.  Execute this command:  `httpd -t -D DUMP_RUN_CFG` and post the results.

Comment: @Allan Added results in question.

Comment: Somewhere in your `httpd.conf` your DocumentRoot is not set properly because `httpd` doesn't have the correct value.  See the value "Main Document Root".  You will need to go through your httpd.conf files (including the custom ones) and make sure you are setting the directive properly; there should be only one and should only be in the main `httpd.conf'

Comment: @Allan `DocumentRoot` and `<Directory ... >` should be `Users/igor/Sites/`?

Comment: Search for DocumentRoot in `httpd.conf`  make it the directory where you want the root of your website to be.

Comment: @Allan Thank you. I changed `Users/igor/Sites/` to `/Users/igor/Sites/`. That fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the `DocumentRoot` directive in your `httpd.conf`.  First, using your favorite editor, search for the `DocumentRoot` directive and add the following:

```
 DocumentRoot "/Users/igor/Sites/MySite/MyLink"
```

Restart Apache so that it reads the updated directive from `httpd.conf`

Comment: Did it, link still goes to `localhost/MyLink` and gives me Error 403 Forbidden.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think anything is configured incorrectly - I think your HTML is wrong. Anything in your Sites folder containing a link like `<a href="/page">page</a>` will ALWAYS go to `localhost/page`.`<a href="page">page</a>`, on the other hand, will resolve to `localhost/~igor/page` as you intend.

The slash preceding the target in the first example redirects it to whatever directory is set as your `DocumentRoot` (e.g. the folder that corresponds to `localhost`).

Comment: Fair enough. Didn't think about it at first for some reason.