# localhost / userdir on macOS High Sierra

Tags: webserver, high-sierra

There's a tutorial here **Setting up a local web server on macOS 10.13 "High Sierra"**

https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-12034

localhost works but user shortname - fails.

What gives?

Answer (score 4):

Like on [Sierra](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/253887/115865) vhosts seem to need to be activated

so:

> sudo vi /etc/apache2/httpd.conf

and uncomment the following lines by removing the hashtag (#)

> .#LoadModule vhost_alias_module libexec/apache2/mod_vhost_alias.so

and

> .#Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

then

> sudo apachectl restart

and you'll be good to go