# Apache2 not running on High Sierra without Homebrew

Tags: homebrew, apache

This is a post I have found on this issue:
[Apache2 (Httpd) not working after update to High Sierra](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/306101/apache2-httpd-not-working-after-update-to-high-sierra)

But I have a situation where httpd is not running
after setting preference -> sharing ->web  sharing on

The relevant factors:

I bought this machine used with Sierra installed.

I upgraded it to High Sierra.

I attempted to set localhost as home page in my browers.

The browser responed by indicating they cannot connect to localhost.

I did some Googling and found the post this references.

I did not install Homebrew on this machine.

I have never used Homebrew.

But there may be a possibility that Homebrew was
installed at some point and upgrades to the system have not undone it.
I do find in /etc/Apache2/ an httpd.conf~previous
and many files in ./extra with ~previous appended to various files.

The question is: how can I verify if Homebrew was installed and if so can I safely run the uninstall script found?

There is a related issue with ethernet interfaces:
When a browser is used to contact localhost and puts up an error claiming it cannot conntect to localhost, I have noticed that I loose access to 
the internet (App Store will not connect claiming I don't have an internet connection).
BUT I can access machines on the local network via file sharing. So I know the interface is working.

I would like to get this straightened out. I do
developement and want localhost to work. I like
to have localhost as a landing pad home page for
my browsers.

Thank you for time and attention
JK

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue:

httpd has to be started via sudo or by root.

This system is a clean install of High Sierra.

The solution was to run commands in terminal to
stop and restart httpd.

The solution to the ethernet
interface issue was to reset the PRAM.